# Average Spend per customer in database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a database (transactions) of spends in a shop by customer. I need to create a report with the average spend (`amount`) per customer (`uid`).

Here's an example of the data:

```
ID     uid     amount
1      C01       6.07
3      C04       5.78
87     C01      45.89
```

Can anybody suggest a query I might use to download a report of average spends for each customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.uid, AVG(m.amount)
FROM MyTable m 
GROUP BY m.uid
```